# Can I use filter not using object.filter python

Tags: python, django, list

I always use filter in `Question.objects.filter()`
but this time, I want to use filter to get the value from a class such as:

```
class Expense():
    amount = ''
    currency = ''
    date = ''
```

and this is my method:

```
def get_expense_list(self, taskId):
    #get expense list
    self.expenseList = [Expense()]
    # get all activity from task 
    self.activiytList = Activity.objects.filter(task_id=taskId)

    for activity in self.activiytList:
        try:    
            self.expenseList.filter(currency=activity.expense_currency, self.expenseList)
            self.expenseList.amount = self.expenseList.expense.amount + activity.expense
        except:
            newExpense = Expense()
            newExpense.currency = activity.currency
            newExpense.amount = activity.amount
            newExpense.date = activity.date
            self.expenseList.append(newExpense)
```

I am creating an expense list from activity list. in `activity.model`, there are objects which are:

```
amount =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
currency =  models.CharField(max_length=5)
date = models.DateField()
```

I want to show in expense list that the amount will add if their currency and date are the same and it will `append()` if there is no existing date and currency.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `filter()` method in the list, so the code you are writing is invalid.

So, ignoring your code, if what you want is:

> I want to show in expense list that the amount will add if their currency and date are the same and it will append() if there is no existing date and currency.

then you'd want to do something along the lines of:

```
def get_expense_list(self, taskId):
    self.expenseList = []
    self.activityList = Activity.objects.filter(task_id=taskId)

    for activity in self.activityList:
        # all existing expenses for this currency and date
        comparisonFunc = lambda x: x.currency == activity.currency and x.date == activity.date
        expenses = filter(comparisonFunc, self.expenseList)

        # if there are no expenses, create a new
        if len(expenses) == 0:
            expense = Expense()
            expense.amount = activity.amount
            expense.date = activity.date
            expense.currency = activity.currency
            self.expenseList.append(expense)
        # otherwise, increase the amount for expenses that were matching
        else:
            for expense in expenses:
                expense.amount += activity.amount
```

You could also do all of this in the database with aggregation.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for understanding what i wanted to show. I actually try to run it and i get this error message "object of type 'filter' has no len()". Thank you so much for your help